# Missing $ inserted in a table

Tags: missing

I'm getting this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.557                            & V_
                                     n \le 1 kV & 1 kV \le V_n \le 69 kV & 6...

? ! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.557                            & V_n \le 1 kV &
                                                  1 kV \le V_n \le 69 kV & 6...

?
```

And this is my table, can anyone help me where should i put the $? Latex is already doing it by itself (i guess), but i really want to know whats wrong here.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Valores de referência para as distorções harmônicas totais de tensão.}
\begin{center}
\label{limites_distorcao}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Indicador} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Tensão Nominal do Barramento}                                                          \\ \cline{2-4} 
                           & V_n \le 1 kV & 1 kV \le V_n \le 69 kV & 69 kV \le V_n \le 230 kV \\ \hline
$DHTvI_i$                   & 7,5\%                  & 6\%                                 & 4\%                                         \\ \hline
$DHTv3_i$                   & 6,5\%                  & 5\%                                 & 3\%                                         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `V_n \le 1 kV` should be in math mode

Comment: `$V_n$` and `$\le$` -> Math mode. Please read an introduction to LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the dollar signs for the math code `V_n` and `\le` which causes the error (as already stated by other users in the comments). Inside a `tabular` every cell is an own box and you need to enable math mode for each one.

In addition to that you have some other issues in your code:

- Don't use the `center` environment but the `\centering` command. The former adds unwanted vertical space and is for text paragraphs only. See [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables) for further details.
- For the physical units and percent values I recommend the great `siunitx` package
- Try to avoid vertical rules in your table and try to use the `booktab` package. Less rules in the table make it look better.
- The use of `{table}[h!]` is one of the most frequent beginner issue as they don't understand the use of floats (In short: they should float!). If you want a table at a certain position in the text then the `table` environment is not a good choice (yes, confusing!). See [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text) and maybe also [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) for more information.

Here a version of your code with the improvements added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% for example text here only
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption} % proper table caption distance
\usepackage{booktabs} % book quality table lines
\usepackage{siunitx} % format SI units
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}} % use comma as decimal marker

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Valores de referência para as distorções harmônicas totais de tensão.}
\centering % don't use {center} environment, which is for text paragraphs only and add unwanted vertical space before and after
\label{limites_distorcao}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Indicador} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Tensão Nominal do Barramento}                                                          \\[.25ex]  
                           & $V_n \le \SI{1}{\kilo\volt} $ & $ \SI{1}{\kilo\volt} \le V_n \le \SI{69}{\kilo\volt} $ & $ \SI{69}{\kilo\volt} \le V_n \le \SI{230}{\kilo\volt} $\\ \midrule
$DHTvI_i$                  & \SI{7,5}{\%}                  & \SI{6}{\%}                                 & \SI{4}{\%}                                         \\ 
$DHTv3_i$                  & \SI{6,5}{\%}                  & \SI{5}{\%}                                 & \SI{3}{\%}                                         \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]